# Azure Elastic Job Agent with Azure Active Directory authentication only enabled

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to use the Elastic Job Agent with Azure Active Directory authentication only enabled on the target Azure SQL instance? I have not seen any documentation that doesn't require a credential with a login and password to be store in the job database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm that, just try and let us know.

Overall Microsoft is pushing the adoption of Active Directory everywhere and I would be surprised to discover that an Elastic Job Agent isn't compatible with  Active Directory authentication only enabled.

The contrary is actually more plausible.

So give it a try and let us know.